# Search_path Changes When Autocommit is enabled

Tags: postgresql

When inserting or updating a table in PostgreSQL v9.2 via psql with autocommit enabled, after the first operation, the search_path changes.  It happens whether I issue an explicit commit or not.

Thank you very much for your help.

```
$ psql -d db_name -U my_user
AUTOCOMMIT is: off
psql.bin (9.2.4)
Type "help" for help

No entry for terminal type "xterm";
using dumb terminal settings.
db_name=> show search_path;
 search_path
-------------
 my_user
(1 row)

db_name=> select session_user, current_user;
 session_user | current_user
--------------+--------------
 my_user      | my_user
(1 row)

db_name=> update state_list set comments='new comments.' where id_state_list = 1;
UPDATE 1
db_name=> commit;
COMMIT
db_name=> show search_path;
 search_path
-------------
 auditor, public
(1 row)

db_name=> select session_user, current_user;
 session_user | current_user
--------------+--------------
 my_user      | my_user
(1 row)

db_name=> select * from state_list;
ERROR: relation "state_list" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from state_list;
                      ^

db_name=>
```

Comment: Got any `ON UPDATE` triggers?

Comment: Yes.  Dangit.  I think that's exactly it.  I need to reset the search_path at the end, don't I?

Comment: Or use the `SET configuration_parameter TO ...` clause in your `CREATE FUNCTION` statements http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createfunction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ON UPDATE` trigger was changing the parameters.

Use the `SET` clause on the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement if you need to override `search_path` within a function.